# How to compare a property in an instance of a model to something

Tags: ember.js

How would I do the following with Ember

My model is as follows

```
var model = [
     {name: "a", type="letter"}, 
     {name: "2", type="number"}, 
     {name: "orange", type="fruit"}
]

{{#each item in model}}
        {{#if item.type == "fruit"}}
               <div>The item in this model matches fruit {{item.name}}</div>
        {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

How would I display a div with this message ONLY if the model instance type equals fruit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers). Your code would look like this:

```
{{#each item in model}}
        {{#if (eq item.type "fruit")}}
               <div>The item in this model matches fruit {{item.name}}</div>
        {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

It is trivial to write your own helper if you just want equality and/or don't want the extra dependency:

```
// app/helpers/eq.js
// for ember-cli with ember.js >=1.13
export default function(lhs, rhs) {
  return lhs === rhs;
}
```